# выравнивание блоков по одному уровню

Tags: html, css

Как можно выровнять блоки, которые идут параллельно друг-другу. Что бы надпись была на одном уровне с `textarea`.Пробовал и `margin` и `padding` но чую, что не там собака зарыта
https://jsfiddle.net/dirkdirk/qbqj35L2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.label_cat{
    display:inline-block;
     width:200px;
    } 
.chose_cat{
    display:inline-block;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 16px;
    resize: none;
    width:200px;
    } 

.label_lang {
    display:inline-block;
     width:200px;
    }
.chose_lang{
    display:inline-block;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 16px;
    resize: none;
     width:200px;
    }

.label_desc{
    display:inline-block;
     width:200px;
    }
.chose_desc{
    display:inline-block;
     width:200px;
    }

.upload_block{
    padding:10px 0px;
}

.label_cat, .label_lang,.label_desc{
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.chose_cat, .chose_lang,.chose_desc{
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="upload_file_info">
        <div class="upload_block">
            <div class="label_cat">chose category</div>
            <textarea type="text" class="chose_cat" disabled></textarea> 
        </div> 
        <div class="upload_block"> 
            <div class="label_lang">chose language</div>
            <textarea type="text" class="chose_lang" disabled></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="upload_block">
            <div class="label_desc">chose description</div>
            <input type="text" name="" class="chose_desc" value="" />
        </div>         
    </div>
```

Comment: Используй vertical-align, только учти что работает только на inline-block и inline, если будет float работать не будет.

Answer (score 0):

можно сделать как-то так

```
.label_cat {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    position: relative;
    top: -5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариант с FlexBox

```css
.upload_block{
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
/*   align-items: center; */
  width: 100%;
}

.label_cat,
.label_lang,
.label_desc,
.chose_cat,
.chose_lang,
.chose_desc{
  flex: 0 200px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

input,
textarea{
  width: 200px;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="upload_file_info">
  <div class="upload_block">
    <div class="label_cat">chose category</div>
    <textarea type="text" class="chose_cat" disabled></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="upload_block">
    <div class="label_lang">chose language</div>
    <textarea type="text" class="chose_lang" disabled></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="upload_block">
    <div class="label_desc">chose description</div>
    <input type="text" name="" class="chose_desc" value="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Про FlexBox: на [русском](http://frontender.info/a-guide-to-flexbox/) и [английском](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Поддержка FlexBox [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex)

[image: Поддержка FlexBox]